# Passing JSON objects around while mutating them

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

How can you construct a JSON object that can be passed around and mutated by several handlers, all while the original reference is updated?

JSON is backed by a Dictionary and Array in Swift, which are both `Struct` data structures. By definition, structs are pass-by-copy.

Here is a simple unit test I've written

```swift
func testMutatingJson() {
    // Test
    var json: JSON = [
        "dict": [String: AnyObject]()
    ]

    json["dict"]["A"] = JSON(["key1": "value1"])
    json["dict"]["A"]["B"] = JSON(["key2": "value2"])

    XCTAssertEqual(json["dict"]["A"]["B"], JSON(["key2": "value2"]))

    let wrapper = Wrapper(json: json["dict"])
    wrapper.doSomething()

    // FAIL: This will fail since json["dict"]["A"]["B"] was copied into `Wrapper`
    XCTAssertEqual(json["dict"]["A"]["B"]["C"], JSON(["key3": "value3"]))
}

class Wrapper {

    var json: JSON

    init(json: JSON) {
        self.json = json["A"]["B"]
    }

    func doSomething() {
        self.json["C"] = JSON(["key3", "value3"])
    }

}
```

I need the original JSON object to be modified as it will then be processed again after `doSomething()`.

I think my best option is to write my own JSON class that is backed by NSMutableDictionary and NSMutableArray. Is there another option?

Comment: `json` != `wrapper.json` You're modifying the one in the wrapper but then you're testing the one in testMutatingJson.

Comment: Exactly. Point is, Dictionary and Array are struct types. Which you can't pass by reference.

Comment: The point is to test whether the original JSON object is modified (I know it won't be, but I was trying to illustrate my intentions). I imagine that my only option is to write a SwiftyJSON equivalent that is backed by NSMutableDictionary and NSMutableArray instead of the Swift structs.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I meant with my second comment. You can't have this reference behavior with SwiftyJSON, for the very reasons you've exposed in your question. So you either have to test the modified copy, or to change your strategy and use classes instead.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the solution, basically - crate a wrapper object that provides reference semantics for the enclosed JSON struct. You might also be able to refactor your code such that you don't keep extra copies of the JSON object around.

Comment: I wouldn't be able to use a struct for JSON as I would then run into the same issue if any children are passed around and mutated. I'm trying to port a large JS library that abuses the fact that json is pass-by-reference.